# how can you make hyper parameters? in orange3

Tags: python-3.x, prediction, xgboost, hyperparameters, orange

I don't see any tools about this. do i have to download other tools?

and 'test and score' how can i get f1 score? mine one only mse, mae comes out

i've searched on internet about orange3 on hyper parameters. couldnt fine any..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.